# Send a form does not pass in the class of action but by the result input of stuts2

Tags: forms, input, struts2

I am using struts2 for my application.

On my JSP, I have a form that sends data to an 'action = "updateBl"' attribute :

```
  <form action="updateBl" method="post" id="form_bl">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="error_message">Veuillez saisir des nombres !</div>
        <input type="text" class="hidden" id="idCommande_poste_ligne" name="commande.idCommande" value="1">
        <input type="text" class="hidden" id="idPostBl" name="idPost" value="">
        <input type="text" class="hidden" id="idBl" name="idBl" value="">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="num_bl">Numero de BL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num_bl" name="bonLivraison.numeroBonLivraison">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="montant_bl">Montant du BL</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="montant_bl" name="bonLivraison.montant">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date_livraison_bl">Date de livraison</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_livraison_bl" name="bonLivraison.dateBonLivraison">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
      <button id="btn_update_bl" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn_bl">Valider</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
  </form>
```

This information is used to update data in database but this form is also used to insert data in database (with other struts code). It works correctly for insert but not for update. This form is the same but some parameters are changed with jQuery (form action, button id, id of some elements, ...).

Here is the code for insert form :

```
<form action="addBl" method="post" id="form_bl">
          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="error_message">Veuillez saisir des nombres !</div>
              <input type="text" class="hidden" id="idCommande_poste_ligne" name="commande.idCommande" value="1">
              <input type="text" class="hidden" id="idPostBl" name="idPost" value="">
              <input type="text" class="hidden" id="idBl" name="idBl" value="">

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="num_bl">Numero de BL</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num_bl" name="bonLivraison.numeroBonLivraison">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="montant_bl">Montant du BL</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="montant_bl" name="bonLivraison.montant">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="date_livraison_bl">Date de livraison</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_livraison_bl" name="bonLivraison.dateBonLivraison">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="clear"></div>
            <button id="btn_update_bl" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn_bl">Valider</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>

        </form>
```

Here is the relevant part in my strusts.xml file:

```
        <action name = "updateBl" class = "sii.dsi.action.DetailsCommandeAction" method = "UpdateBl">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">details</param>
            <param name="commande.idCommande">${commande.idCommande}</param>
        </result>
        <result name="input" type="redirectAction" >accueil</result>
    </action>
```

When the form is submitted, it never goes into the method of my action class: "UpdateBl".
I am always redirected to my "home" donations pages by the "result name =" input "'.

I can not find the problem.

I need help please.

Thank you in advance.

PS: sorry for the bad English, I'm french and I'm using https://translate.google.fr

Answer (score 0):

Something in your code, or in an interceptor (possibly the conversion interceptor) is adding validation errors (the actionErrors or fieldErrors are not empty) to your action which is triggering the framework to redirect back to the "input" result.

I would recommend overriding the validate() method in your action and set a breakpoint.  Have a look at actionErrors and fieldErrors collections to see what they contain.  This should provide a clue as to what is causing the validation errors.

Comment: I never use validate() (I only use execute()) so I don't know what I must do with it ;(.
It's yhe same with actionErrors and fieldErrors.
Can you explain more for me please.
I'm looking for on my side :).

Comment: Override the validate() method in your action for debugging purposes.  Add a break point inside of it.  The properties actionErrors and fieldErrors are inherited from ActionSupport.  Look at these in the debugger and see if either collection has elements in it.  If they do, that is the cause of the redirect back to "input" as something has added a validation error to the action and struts automatically redirects to "input" when a validation error occurs.  The validate() is in addition to execute().